# After updating the WordPress getting a syntax error in the console

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I have updated the WordPress 5.8 and I am getting some errors in the console.

[image].

I have 5-6 custom widgets on my website that are working on the web page but in the admin panel, I am not getting it. It showing blank

[image]

I am getting this error in the console.

[image]

Even my WPBakery plugin also not working correctly.

Does anyone know how to solve it this issue?

Comment: You're getting `javascript` syntax error. For example, on the screen shot you provided, it says, you have a syntax error (a missing closing parenthesis) on line 2 in `common.min.js`. Also you're getting a couple of `404s`! Also regarding your widget, there is a deprecated function that you need to deal with! Your error messages are pretty self-explanatory!

Comment: @Ruvee, Yes you are right, but how to solve that? I haven't changed anything in the common.min.js. I haven't added any function in the widget file.

Comment: It's hard to tell for me or anybody without seeing your javascript files. Maybe your javascript file(s)/function(s)/syntax are no longer compatible with the newer version of wordpress! Like i said it's hard to debug without seeing your actual javascript files.

Comment: @Ruvee, I haven't added any script and the common.min.js file is from the WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cache issue.

1. Right-click on your page
2. Select "Inspect Element"
3. Right-click on the "Reload" button of our browser
4. Select "Empty cache and hard refresh"

If nothing works, it might be a plugin conflict. Try disabling plugins one by one to figure out the culprit.

Comment: @Amarllindra, I cleared the cache, checked in the private browser, but still not getting the widget, and the same error in the console.

Comment: it might be a plugin conflict. Try disabling plugins one by one to figure out the culprit.